# Simplify Typescript decorator function

Tags: typescript

I encountered the following decorator in Typescript:

```
const component: (options: MyCustomOptions) => Function = (options: MyCustomOptions): Function => (controller: string) => {
    // do some things
    options.controller = controller;
    return options;
};

export interface MyCustomOptions extends angular.IComponentOptions {}
```

The first line looks very complex and I would love to refactor it, but I can't understand what it does.  Can someone guide me how to interpret this piece of code?

My best attempt is along the following lines:

```
// component is declared as a function that accepts 1 parameter of type MyCustomOptions, 
// but the output type is unclear (I can infer from the body `return options` later on 
// that this will be of type MyCustomOptions as well, but I can't see this here)
const component: (options: MyCustomOptions) => Function
    // a) I am lost at the double declaration here
    //    options is declared as MyCustomOptions, and then as a Function?
    // b) I also don't understand where the controller comes from or what it does
    //    Is it a parameter? What's the difference with options?
    = (options: MyCustomOptions): Function => (controller: string) => {
```

TSLint complains about the use of `Function`: *"Avoid using the `Function` type. Prefer a specific function type, like `() => void`."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down, everything to the left of the assignment (`=`) is a declaration, everything to the right is the value:

```
const component: (options: MyCustomOptions) => Function
```

Declares a constant `component` that is a function which takes a `MyCustomOptions` and returns a `Function`. Then after the `=`…

```
(options: MyCustomOptions): Function
```

A function that takes a `MyCustomOptions` and returns a `Function`. Everything after this is irrelevant from a typing perspective, but the rest is:

```
 => (controller: string) => { /* … */ return options; }
```

Which is the `Function` that is being returned: one that takes a `string` and returns a `MyCustomOptions`. Note that the arguments and return of this function are not specified by the declaration, it just needs to a be `Function`.

You can remove much of redundancy via type inference and get the same result:

```
const component = (options: MyCustomOptions): Function => (controller: string) => { /* … */ return options; }
```

You could technically get away with not including the `: Function` part because it could be inferred, but it would be inferred as `(string) => MyCustomOptions` instead of `Function`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  It's still unclear to me however.  I understand the declaration type can be left out and inferred, but I like Typescript that it's explicit in that regard.  What I don't understand after the `=` sign is why we need to describe the lambda expression again which takes `MyCustomOptions` as a parameter and returns a `Function`.  We already described this in the declaration type.  And since we already said `MyCustomOptions` is the input parameter, how come we can suddenly define `controller: string` as a parameter as well?

Comment: After the `=` sign, you could leave out the `: Function` but you need the `(options: MyCustomOptions)`.  The `(options: MyCustomOptions)` before the `=` sign is only part of the type annotation of `component`; when you assign a value that is an arrow function, you have to re-declare the parameters.  What is going on with `controller` is that `component` is a function that takes `MyCustomOptions` and _returns another function_ that takes `controller` and runs the code in `{ ... }`.